# How to deactivate a QGIS2WEB basemap?

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

How can I deactivate a selected basemap in QGIS 2.18 and QGIS2WEB 2.34.0 and completely dispense with the use of basemaps?

If I see it right, once a basemap has been selected, I can only choose between different basemaps. Can't deactivate or am I wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think CTRL-click (on Windows) deselects it.

Comment: Thx. That worked.